# UBUNTU stuck at shutdown after connecting to external screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, multiple-monitors, shutdown

I am in deep peril as I come to you. I am writing my thesis and all hell is loose. I have tried various solutions right from installing to everything online for over 20 days now. As a result, I cant remember the last time I had a proper shutdown. I shall explain my problem, the solutions I have tried and my dire need for a solution.

**Problem**

Connect PC to external monitor HP1955(do not know what happened). Work through the day. Shut down the system. Laptop monitor is well lit, and the system seems to be running. Thats it, Nothing works after that. It is stuck on it forever. Past 15 days I have *NOT* been able to shut down other than use hard shutdown power off button!

**From the comments**

Tried `sudo service networking stop`, and got the output`stop:Job failed while stopping`

Tried `sudo service networking status` after the above, and got the output `networking start/running`

**Attempts made**

1) change grub data as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown)

- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`,
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"`
  && `apm power_off=1` in the modules file.

2) Changed the Additional drivers from open source to fglrx-proprietary, which is when the computer crashed majorly. Couldn't get it to boot at all. Used UBUNTU in command mode finally and took back up.

3) Reinstalled the system. Full disclosure: Installing Ubuntu 14.04 along side windows 8 was a three day ordeal, which resulted in it working and still had some issues like, the external monitor should not be connected while boot up else it will hang like mentioned at the top. I didn't bother about it as the system worked and I had other things to do.

- Reinstalled without formatting `/`, keeping `/home`
- Reinstalled with formatting `/`.\, keeping `/home`

Issue still persists. Cant shutdown peacefully at all.

4) `nomodeset` insertion at boot up by pressing `e` and typing nomodeset next to `quiet splash`.

5)     `sudo swapoff -a`; No change [because of this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680212/ubuntu-wont-shutdown-or-freezes-at-splash-screen)

6) There is one more thing about [redis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574209/ubuntu-cant-shutdown-and-the-log-out-screen-just-freezes), but there is no way for me to find out if thats the problem and I am scared as hell being a noob, as I am not able to do anything once the system is stuck `Sysreq` doesn't work. `Esc` Doesn't work.

7) Reinstalling the ubunutu desktop and unity
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
    sudo apt-get install unity

8) [sudo shutdown -h 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown), doesn't work as well.

Somebody please help me. I dont know when my system will crash next. I need hard strong advice.

**Further explanation of problem**

I beleive it has everything to do with dual monitor VGA things. My system has a problem with external monitors always plugging into the VGA. I have never been able to start up with VGA connected. It was all working well until suddenly it started misbehaving and I tried several solutions, before giving up to reinstall and yet same problems.

When I try to remove the external monitor by switching it off from the `display setting`, it does not switch off. It still works like usual. That is usually my cue that I am not going to be able to shutdown properly.

My laptop details are:

```
Memory : 3.3 GiB
Processor: AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2 
Graphics : Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.0)
OS Type  : 64-bit
Disk 137.8 GB
Laptop : HP Pavillion g6
```

Dual boot with windows 8, which I almost never use, but I have my data there.

Comment: Does it shutdown if you disconnect from the internet or, better, stop networking (`sudo service networking stop`) before shutting down?

Comment: Is Networking related to VGA stuff? I will definitely try this tonight. I can restart only at night, as I am running a few things now on my working PC. Thanks for the support. Will update tonight the details. And delete this comment. Thanks. Please support.

Comment: No, not really. However, I have had similar issues with the shutdown hanging because some service is waiting for a response from the network. It will probably not help but it is easy to test and there is a small chance that it might be relevant.

Comment: Hi, So when I tried `sudo service networking stop`, it gives me... "stop:Job failed while stopping". Nothing happens afterwards. Do let know how to proced.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I guess it might be relevant after all. Please add this info to your question and also show the output of `sudo service networking status` *after* running `sudo service networking stop`. Are you mounting anything from a network computer? A samba share perhaps or an NFS drive? Finally, try disconnecting from the internet any way you can and then shutting down. Does it work?

Comment: Output for `sudo service networking status` is "networking start/running". I am not mounting any drive, But I use VPN connections a lot of times. Just connected an external old CRT monitor to my VGA port and usb mouse. I am a noob, just giving you info. Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK. Please add what you told me here about networking to your question and also tell us if disconnecting from your network before trying to shut down makes any difference.

Comment: Hi, Just finihed restarting my system. Disconnected my wifi connection via the computer and it doesn't change anything. Still I have the black screen! So did a hard reboot for the nth time. How do I get more traffic on this post? I am adding the changes. Thank You for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43184/discussion-between-thej-kiran-and-terdon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had everything to do with the vga external screen. My system works well without the connection to it. Shutsdown properly. But once connected, it does not get disconnected. And for the first time in so many days I had a proper shutdown.

Attempting to reset all monitors as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261122/how-to-reset-monitor-settings-to-default-through-terminal), allows a proper shutdown:

```
xrandr -s 0
```

I guess I will have to do it everytime I want to shutdown if I am connected to an external monitor.